# OpportunityTeamMember Name not writable

Tags: apex, opportunity-teams

I am trying to display all the OpportunityTeamMember records in a vf page using a wrapper class. But while assigning name in the for loop in the constructor, its throwing an error

```
Field is not writeable: OpportunityTeamMember.Name
```

Is there any way to display the name of OpportunityTeamMember

In the constructor i am using -

```
  oppList = [SELECT Id,Name, OpportunityAccessLevel, TeamMemberRole
                  FROM OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId = :opp.id];
        for(OpportunityTeamMember opplis:oppList){
            OpportunityTeamMember oppT = new OpportunityTeamMember();
           Oppswrap inWrap = new Oppswrap (oppT);
            inWrap.oppTeam.Name = opplis.Name;
            wrappers.add(inWrap);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is oppTeam in your wrapper, is it an OpportunityTeamMember object?  Why not just set the entire oppTeam object to opplis?

```
inWrap.oppTeam = opplis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider before moving on to the code

- `Name`field on OppTeamMember is [not writable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityteammember.htm).
- You need to set the user and OppId in order to make OppTeamMember work. So, record will, which user is part of the team on what "Opportunity".

**Code sample**

```
OpportunityTeamMember OppTeamMember = new OpportunityTeamMember();
OppTeamMember.UserId = [UserId];
OppTeamMember.OpportunityId = oppLis.Id;
OppTeamMember.OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit';
OppTeamMember.TeamMemberRole = 'Opportunity Team Member';
inWrap.oppTeam = OppTeamMember;
wrappers.add(inWrap);
```

*Code courtesy of [SFDCPoint](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/opportunityaccesslevel-field-not-writable-in-apex/)*